# Tabela temporária que o hibernate cria

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Estou usando **JPA** e **Hibernate 4.3.11** quando roda uma aplicação simples
Para testar a conexão com banco **Firebird 2.5**  o **Hibernate** está gerando
Uma tabela temporária com o inicio *HT_*.

Exemplo:
criou a tabela Cliente e gerou

**Hibernate:**
    `create table HT_Cliente (id integer not null, hib_sess_id CHAR(36))`

Como faço para desabilitar essa funcionalidade no hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

O Hibernate utiliza essas HT_Tables como tabelas temporárias para auxiliar em operações como delete e update.

Neste [post](http://in.relation.to/2005/07/20/multitable-bulk-operations/), o autor explica que há um problema com deletes e updates em cascata, para saber quais registros precisam ser alterados. Ele mostra uma abordagem nativa para a solução do problema e, depois, explica que a criação de HT_Tables pelo Hibernate, é a solução encontrada pelo Hibernate para o que é chamada de **bulk operations** ou **operações em massa**.

Por ser uma abordagem utilizada para garantir a integridade do banco de dados, creio que essa funcionalidade não pode ser desabilitada, conforme também é afirmado no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19929516/3293600).

Comment: Olá, Pedro! Eu posso sugerir algo? Além dos links, incremente mais sua resposta mostrando, mesmo que de forma sucinta, os motivos para que esta tabela seja criada e outras informações que julgar relevante.

Comment: @Dherik grato pela sugestão, veja se a resposta está melhor!